# How to fetch version history of list item and display in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, jsom

I have requirement where I need to fetch the version history of each list item and display in a separate list where a specific column value has been changed. For Example:

1. I have list named "Demo" and it has column Title, Due Date.
2. I need to fetch the version history whenever **Due Date** has been changed and display in a list/page.

Can someone suggest step by step process to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- You need this probably https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/listitemversion_get?view=odsp-graph-online you will get all versions and in code you need check when the date was edited and after it show the changes

> GET 
>   /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/versions/{version-id}?expand=fields

and it return collection of versions:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "id": "1.0",
    "lastModifiedBy": {
    "user": {
        "id": "CE251278-EF9E-4FE5-833C-1D89EEAE68E0",
        "displayName": "Ryan Gregg"
    }
    },
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-09-14T12:34:53.912Z",
    "fields": {  }
}
```

Comment: I want to get the historical/old version history. WF will give only the present data that is being edited.

Comment: edited the answer